# Purpose of instantiation of Service classes

Tags: ruby

I have repeatedly seen a Ruby pattern of initializing objects of Service classes, i.e. classes that have a singular "call" instance method and nothing else.
For example in the `dry-validation` gem (https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-validation/1.8/schemas/) the contract class is initialized, then that instance is used for validation and never used again.
Same with other Service classes, I found multiple tutorials where it is used like `ServiceClass.new(stuff).call()`.
I don't understand why to jump through the additional hoop of object initialization, when you can achieve the same behavior by simply defining a class method that does the job, like `ContractClass.call(example: "hi")` and `ServiceClass.call(stuff)` respectively.

Am I missing something here? Repeatedly initializing one-of objects seems completely pointless to me.

Comment: It's a cheap object. The cost is inconsequential. What's wrong with that pattern? There are often underlying technical reasons for this, but most commonly it's just that it works fine and is familiar to Ruby programmers.

Comment: Single-responsibility principle and information hiding.

Comment: It's not wrong, and I get that it is cheap, my question is not about performance, it just seems like adding artificial overhead to me. I don't understand why a class method would violate single-responsibility and information hiding? Instantiating your Service class generates references to your data inside of the Service object, so how exactly does that help to hide information?

Comment: class method == "things it does", class instance == "thing that it is". Instances provide clear encapsulation (info hiding) and an object with a lifecycle separate from other instances (single responsibility). The beauty of Ruby is that it's flexible and you don't have to do it this way, but making instances is a clear way to say "this is what it is" vs class methods which can be any number of "things it does". Doesn't mean it's required in all scenarios, but it's a common and useful pattern and it has its reasons. But again, Ruby is flexible. Do what makes sense.

Comment: The thing you're missing is that you can just define a `def self.call(...); new(...).call; end` class method in your parent class which gives you the same simple calls but with all the advantages of encapsulation.